# Hooks set up issue for BDD testing

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to run two automated tests for an app with  the same function but with different outcomes (on an Android app but will be using iOS in a few months). One is to turn on notifications in the app and the other test is to skip app notifications.

When these tests individually they pass however when I run sequentially the second test fails every single time.

I am getting this error message:

```
     Error in "1: Given I can tap the first next button for the My Garden app"
Error: Can't call click on element with selector "~Next" because element wasn't found
    at async CarouselPage.tapOnNextButton (/Users/xxx/Documents/project_wdio-3/features/screens/carouselPages.js:12:9)
    at async World.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Documents/project_wdio-3/features/step-definitions/carouselPages_steps.js:7:2)
```

I know it's a hooks issue however I totally stuck and I need some feedback regarding how to fix this issue. Plus I will be integrating iOS so I hoping it won't occur testing that app (if that makes sense)

Here's the code:

Feature file:

```
Feature:  notifications

      @regressionTest @notifications
      Scenario: As a brand new user I can turn on notifications
            Given I can tap the first next button for the My Garden app
            And I tap the second next button on the second page of the onbarding carousel
            And  I can view the next button on the final page of the onboarding carousel to view the sign up page
            And I tap the I have an account button
            And I enter my registered email
            When I enter my registered password
            And I tap the sign in button to view my signed in page
            Then I tap the turn on notfications button


      @regressionTest @notifications
      Scenario: As a brand new user I can skip notifications
            Given I can tap the first next button for the My Garden app
            And I tap the second next button on the second page of the onboarding carousel
            And  I can view the next button on the final page of the onboarding carousel to view the sign up page
            And I tap the I have an account button
            And I enter my registered email
            When I enter my registered password
            Then I tap the skip icon to ignore notifications
```

Screen Objects

```
class notifcations {
   
    get notificationButton () {
        return $('~Okay');
    }

    get skipNotifcations () {
        return $('~Skip');
    }
    
    
   

   


}

module.exports = new notifcations();
```

Step definition file

```
const { When, Then } = require ('@wdio/cucumber-framework');
const RhsNofications  = require ('../screens/notifications')


Then(/^I tap the turn on notfications button$/,async() => {
    await driver.switchContext("NATIVE_APP");
    RhsNofications.notificationButton.click();
    await driver.pause(15000);
});


Then(/^I tap the skip icon to ignore notfications$/,async () => {
    await driver.switchContext("NATIVE_APP");
    RhsNofications.skipNotifcations.click();
    await driver.pause(5000);
    
    
});
```

Hooks

Here's a hooks solution I tried in the Wdio file. It didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a chat with the developer of webdriverIO  and he recommended the following in this instance Reload Session.  Here's the documentation

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/reloadSession/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I also want to add this.  Add this to end of the WDIO config.js file.  It will the app to start with a fresh slate every single time.

```
beforeScenario: function (uri, feature, scenario, sourceLocation, context) {
        browser.launchApp();
    },

    afterScenario: function (uri, feature, scenario, result, sourceLocation, context) {
             browser.closeApp();
    },
```